# C# windows client app datagridview binding to datarow array with linq query

Tags: c#, linq, datagridview, binding, ado.net

I know my code is doing something right, because when I run it, I get 1 row of data in the datagridview control, which is what I expect, because only 1 row matches the condition (Middle Name = Boy).

But the datagridview does not show me the fields in my table.

It shows me something odd that I don't follow.  [image: See Screenshot]

Am I supposed to bind to something else?

Code follows below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;

namespace ECLLookupRegister
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {


        DataRow[] CurrentRows;
        DataTable MasterTable;
…

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CurrentRows = GetAllAgentUsersData().Select("Middle = 'Boy'", "Middle", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows);
    this.dataGridView1.DataSource = CurrentRows;            
}

private DataTable GetAllAgentUsersData()
{

    DataTable ReturnTable;

    ReturnTable = null;

    string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DbConn"].ToString();

    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
        {
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("GetAllAgentUsers", con);
            da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            da.Fill(ds);
            ReturnTable = ds.Tables[0];
        }

    return ReturnTable;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wow, this works!

this.dataGridView1.DataSource = CurrentRows.CopyToDataTable();`